# How to tell NuGet for past migration

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

So I copy project solution form my friend and all migration where lost so if I change like username length to 129 and say to console Add-Migration it gives me empty  migration? 
So no UP and DOWN

So how do i  need to do , to tell NuGet  for past migration do i need to run migration all over or do i need to do something else ? I have (migrations folder )?? all help is welcome*

[image: So here is the snapshot]

I did export and import data base in MySql

Comment: What does this have to do with NuGet or MySQL? What do you mean by migration in this context?

Comment: i need to tell nuget about that i try get-migrations but i dose not work , and it have to do with mysql because that database is using for migrations.

Comment: *What* are you migrating? Or are you creating an update to an existing NuGet package that you've written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which migration to run like this:

```
update-database -TargetMigration:201405131513421_Inital
```

And then you can update to latest version like this:

```
update-database
```

Comment: I will try that but what i want to do is next , i dont know if there is command for that.
I need if i for example change something in class User , for example  [Required,MaxLength(129)] and then tell in Package Manager Console i wrote add-migration ChangeLength that entity framework create that migration.

Comment: If your database is at latest version (i.e. you've just successfully done an `update-database`) then you should be able to write "add-migration ChangeLength" and EF should create your migration. If it doesn't do this then tell us the error. You can add `-verbose` switch to `add-migration` to get extra details.

Comment: Also can you paste the code for User, so we can see the definition of the field you're trying to update.

Comment: Thank you for help sir! I own you , helps a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The following will update the database to the latest migration

```
Update-Database
```

If that does not work, you can apply the migrations individually

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration Initial
```